# How to change a simple func into recursive one in django rest API

Tags: recursion, while-loop, django-rest-framework

I have an object, which is able to have its own child, that child also has own child, and so on. All of them have the field total_amount_active_channels, which by default is 0. When I change this field in any object (in parents and child as well), the changes should affect in all previous parents.
For example:

```
A (parent): if changes = 0,  total_amount_active_channels =2
B (child of A): if changes = 0,  total_amount_active_channels =2
C (child of B): if changes = 1,  total_amount_active_channels =2
D ( child of C): if changes = 1,  total_amount_active_channels = 1
```

But anytime when I open any object, it should plus its own total_amount_active_channels+the total_amount_active_channels of its child.
Now it works with this code, but I want to remake it by recursion. I am not good at recursion!

my view:

```
class CircuitEditView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitEdit
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOpuOnly,)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        a = bool(self.get_object().first)
        instance = serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user.profile)
        if a != instance.first:
            get_total_amount_active_channels(obj=instance.id_object, instance=instance)
```

my service.py:

```
def get_total_amount_active_channels(obj, instance):
    cir = instance.id_object
    while True:
        if cir.id_parent is None:
            if instance.first ==True:
                cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels)+1
                cir.save()
            else:
                cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) - 1
                cir.save()

            break

        if instance.first == True:
            cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) + 1
            cir.save()
            cir = cir.id_parent
        else:

            cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) - 1
            cir.save()
            cir = cir.id_parent
```

models of Circuit:

```
class Circuit(models.Model):
    id_parent = models.ForeignKey('Circuit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    num_circuit = models.CharField('Номер канала', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)   
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first = models.BooleanField('Используется/Не используется', default = False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='circ_cust', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    id_object = models.ForeignKey(Object, related_name='circ_obj', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

model of Object:

```
    
    id_parent = models.ForeignKey('Object', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='parents', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100)
    
    num = models.CharField('Количество задейственных каналов', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    
    amount_channels = models.CharField('Количество каналов', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True) 
    total_amount_channels = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    total_amount_active_channels = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: could you add models.py also

Comment: I have already added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do my recursive approach like this:

```
def get_total_amount_active_channels(obj, instance):
    cir = instance.id_object

    # update this node
    if instance.first:
        cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) + 1
    else:
        cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) - 1

    cir.save()

    if cir.id_parent != None:
        # check for recursion
        get_total_amount_active_channels(obj, cir.id_parent)
```

Anyways, recursion could cause memory problems if the tree you're navigating is big enough and tends to be slower than iterative approaches. I would improve the iterative approach rather than implementing a recursive approach.

If you remove redundant code in your iterative approach, it could be great. I would do something like this:

```
def get_total_amount_active_channels(obj, instance):
    cir = instance.id_object
    while True:
        # update this node
        if instance.first:
            cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) + 1
        else:
            cir.total_amount_active_channels = int(cir.total_amount_active_channels) - 1

        cir.save()

        if cir.id_parent is None:
            break
        else:
            cir = cir.id_parent
```